# Cancel button on UISearchController is not working sometimes

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uikeyboard, uisearchcontroller

I am facing an issue with the UISearchController in iOS 8. The problem is that whenever I am clicking on cancel button, instead of cancelling the search operation, it is bringing up the keyboard. 
Follow below steps to reproduce the issue -

1. Click on the search bar.
2. Type a word and click on search(This will
   dismiss the keyboard)
3. Now click on cancel.

Now, instead of dismissing the search, the keyboard is popping up for entering the text. This usually happens when I am tapping at the right half of cancel button and it can be reproduced even in standard iOS apps like Contacts app. I would like to dismiss search when cancel is tapped.

Is there any workaround for this issue?

Comment: Surprised to see very few or no discussion about this issue although the issue seems very straightforward and easily visible on most apps.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the search bar as a first responder programatically when the cancel button is clicked which will prevent the keyboard from coming up.

```
[searchController.textField resignFirstResponder];
```

Comment: Actually, I am not getting a callback to the delegate method -searchBarCancelButtonClicked when the cancel button is tapped. It is treating it as if I have clicked on the search bar again.